# Kotlin/Parse : com.parse.ParseObject cannot be cast to

Tags: kotlin, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

I'm trying to do a Parse request but I got this error :

> com.parse.ParseObject cannot be cast to
>   com.mysapp.mys.common.model.Lesson

but it doesn't enter inside the subscribe after the return of the request.
**The answer of the server is good because I have the log of it on real-time.**

I believe I have a problem when I receive the answer and when I cast implicitly with the lambda. But I don't know how to achieve it in another way.

```
fun getLessons(coach: Boolean, lessonType: LessonType?, date: Date?, position: LatLng, distance: Double): Single<List<Lesson>> {
        val params = hashMapOf<String, Any?>()
        if (lessonType == null){
            params["lessonType"] = ""
        }
        else{

        }
        params["lessonType"] = 12

        params["date"] = date
        params["geoPoint"] = ParseGeoPoint(44.557514, -0.86099)
        params["within"] = 4935.772
        Log.e("params : ", "lessonType: " + params.get("lessonType") + "| date : " + params.get("date").toString()
                + " | geoPoint: " + params.get("geoPoint") + " | within: "+ params.get("within"))
        return ParseObservable.callFunction<List<Lesson>>("getSessions", params).singleOrError()
    }
```

how I treat it :

```
disposables.add(repository.getLessons(false, lesson, dateSelected, position, distance.toDouble())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe({ lessons ->
                    Log.e("LESSONS", lessons.toString())
                    removeCanceledLessonsAndEmit(lessons)
                }, Throwable::printStackTrace)
        )
```

I don't know how Parse is working so that's why I have copied on this

request who already exists in the project :

```
fun getAverageRating(coachId: String): Single<HashMap<String, Int>> {
        val params = hashMapOf<String, String>()
        params["coachId"] = coachId
        return ParseObservable.callFunction<HashMap<String, Int>>("getAverageRating", params).singleOrError()
    }
```

how it's treated :

```
disposables.add(repository.getAverageRating(coachId)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({ rating ->
                    if (rating > 0) {
                        ratingBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        ratingBar.rating = rating
                    } else
                        ratingBar.visibility = View.GONE

                }, Throwable::printStackTrace)
        )
```

If you need any details feel free to ask me.

Comment: In subscribe, I need to convert the `ParseObject` to a **subclass** of `ParseObject`. Do you have any info on that. I get a `ClassCastExpection` when I try to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method `getSessions` is returning a `ParseObject` instead of returning a `Lesson` type object. Try to check the type and return appropriate model from that.

Change `getLessons` return type to this

```
   ParseObservable.callFunction<List<Any>>("getSessions", params).singleOrError()
```

and treat like this to check return type.

```
disposables.add(repository.getLessons(false, lesson, dateSelected, position, distance.toDouble())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe({ lessons ->
                    Log.e("LESSONS", lessons.toString())
                    //removeCanceledLessonsAndEmit(lessons)
                }, Throwable::printStackTrace)
        )
```

To get lessons in `com.mysapp.mys.common.model.Lesson` POJO you can do any of the followings

1. Annotate `Lessons` class with `@ParseClassName("Lesson")` [See this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194064/com-parse-parseobject-cannot-be-cast-to)
2. Cast parse object to JSON and use gson to convert to Lesson POJO

Finally, don't forget to do the necessary changes to this line ***ParseObservable.callFunction>("getSessions", params).singleOrError()***

Comment: Yes now it entered in the `subscribe` ! But I still need to cast it into a `List<Lesson>`. I already tried the following which is not working :
`val list = lessons.filterIsInstance<Lesson>()
                    if (list.size != lessons.size){
                        Log.e("CAST", "CAST FAILED")
                    }`

Comment: Casting won't help inside subscribe, you need to return lessons from `getSessions` method. You can add that method in your answer so that I can check.

Comment: the getSessions is on the server side and return automatically `ParseObject`

Comment: But I'm wondering something, why in the example I gave into my post (`averageRating`) it also returns a `ParseObject` but the `cast` to `Int` is working ?

Comment: I think that just works for primitives, not for objects. Please, check the answer for the update.

Comment: Finally after some talk I understood that a `ParseObject` is like a `JSON` so I can read data like this :
`name = parseObject.getString("name")`